# Compare two non coherent data vba

Tags: excel, vba, find, compare

The problem at hand is I have to compare two sets of data,one is initial requirement and other is completed sheet.
the problem here is I have to compare two IDS(all data comes under specific Id's) and the number of components under the same ID's are also not the same because first one is initial requirements,second one is completed sheet where in few items in from the initial sheet maybe skipped.

for example:
sheet 1

```
A          B            C
item id    productcode  productname
1
           tc7868976    bolt
           tc7687678    nut
2
           tc65799      screw
           tc98908      bolt
```

sheet 2

```
A          B             C
item id    productcode   productname
1
           tc7868976     bolt
2
           tc65799       screw
           tc98908       bolt
           tc5657        bolt(1)
```

Now i have to check if items in sheet 2 are there in sheet one,even the row numbers dont match what do i do?
I tried for loops but it is becoming very tedious because the volume of data is very high,around 100 columns.
I have simplified the example - would someone kindly help me out with the logic?

Comment: Are the item ids on different rows to the product information (as per your samples)? If they are on the same row do they repeat down the column, or are they followed by blank cells? What is the output? That is, what do you do if a product in sheet 2 is not in sheet 1?

Comment: if a product in sheet two aint in sheet 1 u can just skip it,no problem,sheet one is super set and sheet two is sub set,the column which contains ids are follwed by blanks,yes they are in different rows,output is if all items in sheet two are in sheet1 it shud say true else false

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example, that will just place a True value on a column, when it matches a Product code within a Item ID:

```
Sub tt()
Dim IR, CS As Variant
Dim column_IR, column_CS As Integer
Dim id_corresp_IR(100000), id_corresp_CS(100000) As Integer

IR = 1 'initial requirements sheet name or number, IR = "Sheet1" is valid also
CS = 2 'Complete sheet name or number, CS = "Sheet2" is valid also

column_IR = 1 'column to match item IDs on the initial requirements Sheet
column_CS = 1 'column to match item IDs on the Complete Sheet
column_p_IR = 2 'column to match product code IDs on the initial requirements Sheet
column_p_CS = 2 'column to match product code IDs on the Complete Sheet
MT_IR = 9 'column to place a Match mark on the initial requirements sheet

NR_IR = Sheets(IR).Cells(Rows.Count, column_IR).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column_IR to be matched
NR_CS = Sheets(CS).Cells(Rows.Count, column_CS).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column_CS to be matched
NR_p_IR = Sheets(IR).Cells(Rows.Count, column_p_IR).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column_p_IR to be matched
NR_p_CS = Sheets(CS).Cells(Rows.Count, column_p_CS).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column_p_CS to be matched

k = 0

'Compare item id that match, allocates position on array id_corresp_IR and id_corresp_CS, for initial requirements and the complete sheet
For i = 2 To NR_IR
    For j = 2 To NR_CS
        If Sheets(IR).Cells(i, column_IR) = Sheets(CS).Cells(j, column_CS) And Not Sheets(IR).Cells(i, column_IR) = "" Then
            id_corresp_IR(k) = i
            id_corresp_CS(k) = j
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'find in which rows each subset of product IDs are located within item IDs that were matched
'and then run a match loop for product IDs
Sheets(IR).Cells(NR_p_IR + 1, column_IR) = "_" 'these will serve as delimitators since we are going to use .End(xlDown) below
Sheets(CS).Cells(NR_p_CS + 1, column_CS) = "_" 'these will serve as delimitators since we are going to use .End(xlDown) below
For Z = 0 To k - 1
    row_ir_bg = id_corresp_IR(Z)
    row_ir_end = Sheets(IR).Cells(id_corresp_IR(Z), column_IR).End(xlDown).Row - 1
    row_cs_bg = id_corresp_CS(Z)
    row_cs_end = Sheets(CS).Cells(id_corresp_CS(Z), column_CS).End(xlDown).Row - 1
    For a = row_ir_bg To row_ir_end
        For b = row_cs_bg To row_cs_end
            If Sheets(IR).Cells(a, column_p_IR) = Sheets(CS).Cells(b, column_p_CS) And Not Sheets(IR).Cells(a, column_p_IR) = "" Then
                Sheets(IR).Cells(a, MT_IR) = True
            End If
        Next b
    Next a
Next Z
Sheets(IR).Cells(NR_p_IR + 1, column_IR) = ""
Sheets(CS).Cells(NR_p_CS + 1, column_CS) = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: tanks a lot,but this comparison isnt like if it isnt in same rows it should return false,its lik say id1 is in row 2 in sheet 1 and id 1 is in row 5 in sheet 2,it should find id 1 and then compare the elements under it(again,elements under it are not same,id 1 in sheet 1 might have 3 elements and id 1 in sheet 2 might have 2 elements,it shud jus check if these 2 elements in sheet 2 are in sheet 1 and return true or false)

Comment: ok, then there are two steps: 1) find which 'items id' (Col A) match. 2) for each one of those that match in step 1, which 'product code' (Col B) match, and mark them true. Is that it?

Comment: I will edit my code, accordingly. Not very clean, but should do it.

Comment: tanks a lot mate! helps a lot!